# I have a spreadsheet with rows of text in a single column

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

IE:

```
  23    HL*3*2*23*0
  24    PAT*19
  25    NM1*QC*1*CUSTOMER*COLE
  26    N3*228 PINEAPPLE CIRCLE
  27    N4*CORA*PA*15108
  28    DMG*D8*19940921*M
  29    CLM*945405*5332.54***12>B>1*Y*A*Y*Y*P
  30    HI*BK>2533
  31    LX*1
  32    SV1*HC>J2941*5332.54*UN*84***1
  33    DTP*472*RD8*20110511-20110511
  34    REF*6R*1099999731
  35    NTE*ADD*GENERIC 12MG CARTRIDGE
  36    LIN**N4*00013264681
  37    CTP****7*UN
```

I want to populate column C with the text from row 29 as a min row with "945405" all the way to row 37 (the one with the text "CTP" in it). I cannot do this in VBA due to permissions. Is there a formula that will grab this value (it is always CLM * xxxxxx *...), assign it to column C using the "CLM" as the min row and CTP as the MAX row all the way through the SS? IE:

```
  23    HL*3*2*23*0 
  24    PAT*19  
  25    NM1*QC*1*CUSTOMER*COLE  
  26    N3*228 PINEAPPLE CIRCLE 
  27    N4*CORA*PA*15108    
  28    DMG*D8*19940921*M   
  29    CLM*945405*5332.54***12>B>1*Y*A*Y*Y*P   945405
  30    HI*BK>2533                              945405
  31    LX*1                                    945405
  32    SV1*HC>J2941*5332.54*UN*84***1          945405
  33    DTP*472*RD8*20110511-20110511           945405
  34    REF*6R*1099999731                       945405
  35    NTE*ADD*GENERIC 12MG CARTRIDGE          945405
  36    LIN**N4*00013264681                     945405
  37    CTP****7*UN                             945405
  38    NM1*DK*1*PATIENT*DEBORAH****XX*1    
  39    N3*123 MAIN ST*APT B
```

****Update*****

I was given permissions in VBA. How would I loop this?

Here is a clearer picture of what I am trying to accomplish
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o24nv.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `=MID(Source_Cell, Start_Position, Desired_Length)` function to pull the substring. In your case it would be:

```
=MID(B29, 5, 6)
```

You can then put this formula in all of  the cells you'd like it to be in.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way though to set it so the formula executes between rows? There are 100s of 1000s of rows so applying it manually would be very time consuming. I know how to do this with C# and powershell, but just straight as a formula on the spreadsheet?

Comment: what do you mean by "between rows"? like automate it so that it goes to each new CLM and applies it?

Comment: Like it applies the formula when the cell starts with CLM, and stops applying when it hits the end (in this case CTP). Is this something that I can loop through using the VB editor? Sorry, I am less familiar with excel functionality :(